# Background image smooth zoom

Tags: css

I want my background image to zoom in when user is zooming in the site. And also I need scrollbars to appear.
For example [here](https://online.sberbank.ru/CSAFront/index.do)

Let the background begin to zoom in when the screen's width is 882px
Before this, the width of the background must stay the same size.
I can write something like:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url('https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 882px) {
  body {
    background-size: 350%;
  }
}
```

But when the screen's width is 400px image is too small.
On the top and on the bottom are some areas without a background image, that looks awful.

[[image: background image 400px]]

There is the same problem when the size of the screen is 250px.

[[image: background image 250px]]

So I have to write a few more media requests. This method is inconvenient. Values of the percentages depend on the size of the image. And the scale of the background changes steeply, not smoothly.

Please tell me, how else can I make the background image to zoom in..

Answer (score 0):

I have taken up a grid container having a single row and column which is taking entire screen size and assigning background-image to it.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(882px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}
.container > div{
    background: url("https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container"><div>
            Hello
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```